# ! I can't find file `pgflibrarytikz*.code.tex'

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, tikz-styles

I can compile the following LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,plotmarks}   

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\end{document}
```

However, the process fails if I include any of the following lines:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

The log file begins with:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6) (format=pdflatex 2011.1.14)
```

The same error occurs with a newer "format=pdflatex":

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6) (format=pdflatex 2012.3.8)
```

The respective errors are:

```
! I can't find file `pgflibrarytikzdecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex'.
! I can't find file `pgflibrarytikzpositioning.code.tex'.
! I can't find file `pgflibrarytikzfit.code.tex'.

! I can't find file `pgfplots.code.tex'.
```

What could be the problem? Is there a way to "install" these tikz options?

---

Edit: When I follow the "\listfiles" suggestion in the first comment, these are the most relevant lines:

```
tikz.sty 2006/10/17 v1.10 (rcs-revision 1.68)
pgf.sty 2006/10/11 v1.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
```

So, it seems I should update these packages.

Comment: You're using an old version of PGF. You can check your version by including `\listfiles` in your preamble and looking at the list near the end of your `.log` file. The current version is 2.1.

Comment: `pgfplots` is not a tikz library. This is a package itself.

Comment: Thanks, you could make it an answer. Updating the packages did the work.